# Get-FileHash not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check a file MD5 hash against an array of hashes, using `Get-FileHash`. Consider this simple code:

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\Files'

$md5hash = @(
'6edaaec9c5b9cea3f035065d7283ca07', 
'023c80233d32b33128841038491af8c7',
'f58d26a3fe697efd84c2a841140bc524')

$dir | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($md5hash -contains (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5)) 
    {
        Write-Output "Match found." 
    } 
    else 
    {
        Write-Output "No match.
    }
}
```

'No match' is always returned, but I can verify the hashes are correct manually:

```
$dir -contains '6edaaec9c5b9cea3f035065d7283ca07'
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-FileHash` does not return a string, but an object, which you could easily verify by simply running it once:

```
PS> Get-FileHash test.txt -Algorithm md5

Algorithm Hash                             Path
--------- ----                             ----
MD5       B53F079809559E4E8C2B13863B153ABF Home:\test.txt
```

So, change your code to

```
$md5hash -contains (Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm MD5).Hash
```